# Skip logins in PHP unit test within Zendframework 2

Tags: php, unit-testing, authentication, ldap

i'm new to php unit and reading the examples from php unit docs. I try a test to get the index page of the target app. I get error pasted below, guessing it is because the app requires logins, ldap logins. I wonder how I can skip it or set up a username and password in advance.

Error:
Failed asserting response code "200", actual status code is "302"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple ZF2 Unit Tests for a controller using ZfcUser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354456/simple-zf2-unit-tests-for-a-controller-using-zfcuser)

Comment: I need to set up password and username, which is different form another question Marek posted.